# Array to string conversion in foreach

Tags: arrays, foreach

Hi,

I am getting an array for string conversion when using the code below:

```
$sort_order = array();
foreach (getAll() as $field) {
        $sort_order[$field->name] = query("SELECT sort_order
                FROM field_table
                WHERE field_name = '$field->name'");                
      $o->tag[$field->name] = $field->title. $sort_order[$field->name];
            }
```

The error says there is an Array to string conversion in line 6. Why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`query` will return an array, so you need to do something like:

```
 $result = query("SELECT sort_order
            FROM field_table
            WHERE field_name = '$field->name'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
sort_order[$field->name] = $row['sort_order'];
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now I get a Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the query returns an array, which is directly assigned to the variable. Please try this :

```
  $sort_order = array();
  foreach (getAll() as $field) {
     $result = query("SELECT sort_order
        FROM field_table
        WHERE field_name = '$field->name'");

     while($res = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $sort_order = $res['sort_order'];
     }

     $o->tag[$field->name] = $field->title.$sort_order;
  }
```

Comment: I tried but got this error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: sorry, same error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object

Comment: Is your database connection proper.?
$connect = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$result = $connect->query("SELECT sort_order FROM field_table  WHERE field_name = '$field->name'"); This error may come if the database is not properly connected.

Comment: Its properly connected. I can get the value of $field->title with no problem.

Comment: Sorry, i still get the same error. Seems like fetch_array() cant be used here.